# Excel Macro Requires Multiple Executions to function correctly

Tags: vba

Good morning,
I am having some issues in running an Excel macro I've developed. It was working fine before, but the past couple months it requires me to delete data and re-run it for the intended results.
The purpose of this code is to copy and paste from one workbook to another, copying a series of specific ranges to the corresponding ranges in the second workbook starting at the last blank row. The code is as follows:

```vb
Sub Import_Data

    DimFileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating=False
    FileToOpen=Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="File Import", _
                        FileFilter:="ExcelFiles(*.xlsx*),*.xlsx*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook=Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("$AQ$2:$AQ$1500").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("$C$2:$C$1500").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        '......
        Open.Application.CutCopyMode=False
        OpenBook.Close False
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating=True

End Sub
```

Again, when I run it the first time it transposes rows, columns, and data or it omits data altogther. When I delete the imported data and rerun the macro, it imports the data correctly. I just want to figure out a way to make it work the right way the first time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There are errors in your code which make it look like it wasn't directly copy-pasted in, but there's nothing there which would explain the behavior you describe.

Comment: I appreciate it! Due to security restrictions, I am unable to directly copy and paste, so I appreciate that fix.

Comment: Is there perhaps a validation that I can add in to prevent these errors?

Comment: Your code is pretty straightforward and it's very difficult to imagine it resulting in the pasted data being missed (unless there's no data in the selected workbook) or transposed.